# Override of HTML Style="" element

Tags: css, wordpress

I am having an issue with my site that I am building.

I have a piece of code:
`<div id="content" class="site-content" style="min-height: calc(100vh - 211px);">`

I can't edit the HTML directly since it's wordpress -_-.

I want to change calc(100vh to calc(0vh

I have done some googling and found the css !important tag.

`element.style {
    min-height: calc(0vh - 211px) !important;
}`

I tried this and it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Your selector should be `#content {}` and not `element.style`. Later one applies to `<element class="style"></element>`

Comment: Just curious, why do you want to set a negative height?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
div#content {
    min-height: calc(0vh - 211px) !important;
}

.site-content{
    background: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="content" class="site-content" style="min-height: calc(100vh - 211px);">
test
</div>
```

Comment: This was the solution I used, Thanks. I tried up voting but can't until my rep is 15 +.

Answer (score 0):

You should be OK just targeting it this way:

```
.site-content {
    min-height: calc(0vh - 211px) !important;
}
```

If not, it's an ugly method to use, but this will work as a last resort:

```
.site-content[style="min-height: calc(100vh - 211px);"] {
    min-height: calc(0vh - 211px) !important;
}
```

It makes the assumption, though, that the initial inline style is not going to change, so use this style at your discretion!

Comment: I think he doesn't need to do `[style="min-heigth(...)"]`, it should work with only `[style]`

Comment: True @OscarArranz

Answer (score -1):

In order to override the style tag you have to do this in your css file:

```
#content[style] {
  min-height: calc(0vh - 211px);
}
```